# Bokeh reset figure on success widget click

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a widget callback function that resets the entire plot to its initialized state but it is not working. I expect the users to click Sample as many times as they want then be able to reset the vbar plot to its initialized state.

I have already created the python callback function and used some print functions to debug a bit but the plot is not resetting.

```
plot2 = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=int(1.618*600), title="Block Party",
              tools="crosshair,reset,save",
              x_range=[0, 11], y_range=[0, max(counts)])

plot2.vbar(x='x', top='y', source=source2, width=0.8)
"""
Set up widgets
"""
title2 = TextInput(title="Plot Title", value='Blocks')
sample = Button(label="Sample", button_type="success")
reset = Button(label="Reset", button_type="success")

# Callback
def reset_window_2():
    global source2
    print("I was clicked")
    np.random.seed(42)
    unique, counts = np.unique(np.random.randint(low=1, high=11, size=100), return_counts=True)
    source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=unique, y=counts))
    plot2 = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=int(1.618 * 600), title="Block Party",
                   tools="crosshair,reset,save",
                   x_range=[0, 11], y_range=[0, max(counts)])
    plot2.vbar(x='x', top='y', source=source2, width=0.618)
    reset.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(p=plot2), code="""
            plots2.reset.emit()
        """))
    print("Check 2")


reset.on_click(reset_window_2)

# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs1 = column(title1, sigma, mu)
inputs2 = column(title2, sample, reset)
tab1 = row(inputs1, plot1, width=int(phi*400))
tab2 = row(inputs2, plot2, width=int(phi*400))
tab1 = Panel(child=tab1, title="Like a Gauss")
tab2 = Panel(child=tab2, title="Sampling")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
curdoc().title = "Sample Dash"
```

The print functions occur but the reset does not. Any ideas on how to reset the entire plot to init?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bokeh plots don't show up merely by virtue of being created. In Bokeh server apps, they have to be put in a layout and added to `curdoc`. You presumably did this:

```
curdoc.add_root(plot2)
```

If you want to replace `plot2` in the browser, it has to be replaced in `curdoc`. The `plot2` you create in your callback is just a local variable in a function. It pops into existence for the duration of the function, only exists inside the function, then gets thrown away when the function ends. You haven't actually done anything with it. To actually replace in `curdoc`, it will be easier to store the plot in an explicit layout:

```
lauyot = row(plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Then in your callback, you can *replace* what is in the layout:

```
layout.children[0] = new_plot
```

***All that said***, I would actually advise against doing things this way. The general, always-applicable best-practice for Bokeh is:

> Always make the smallest change possible.

A Bokeh plot has dozen of sub-components (ranges, axes, glyphs, data sources, tools, ...) Swapping out an entire plot is a *very heavyweight operation* Instead, what you should do, is just update the data source for the plot you already have, to restore the data it started with:

```
source2.data = original_data_dict  # NOTE: set from plain python dict
```

That will restore the bars to their original state, making the smallest change possible. This is the usage Bokeh has been optimized for, both in terms of efficient internal implementation, as well as efficient APIs for coding.

Comment: Ok. I tried this but it does not work with success widget on_click

Comment: It's impossible to speculate without a complete minimal code example. Otherwise, there are very many examples of the pattern I mention in the docs and examples.